# Laravel how do i display a row by passing in an attribute in my model

Tags: mysql, laravel, search, model

I am trying to display the object for my student based off an attribute called "stn" in the students table. I was able to display it when I used the Primary Key, but when using an attribute, the function returns nothing, when it used to return an object.

```
@foreach($users as $user)

    @foreach($user->contactlogs as $logs)

        {{ $logs->students }}

    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

This used to display the student object, now it comes with nothing, these are my models

```
class ContactLog extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'contactlogs';

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id');
    }
    public function students()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Student::Class);
    }

}
```

---

```
class Student extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'students';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function contactlogs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ContactLog::class);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to display the information the following way

```
    $student = Student::where('stn', '=', $request->stn)->first();

    $log->student_id = $student->id;
```

where it runs a search for the stn and gets back the first match, these are unique so it should work, then it stores the ID, and in the view, i can just display the STN instead of the ID

Answer (score 0):

Well in your controller you must have something like this:

```
public function yourAction(){
    $users = ContactLog::with('users', 'students')->get();
    return view('your.view' , compact('users'));
}
```

then in your view you have to do this:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
{{ $user->users->name }}
{{ $user->students->name }}
@endforeach
```

And you can do the same for students too:

```
public function yourAction(){
     $students = Student::with('users', 'contactlogs')->get();
      return view('your.view' , compact('students'));
 }
```

the same for your view

```
@foreach($students as $student)
    {{ $student->users->attr }} //attr is the attribute from users
    {{ $student->contactlogs->attr }}// attr is the attribute from contaclogs
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help out, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Try contactlogs()  instead of contactlogs

@foreach($users as $user)

```
@foreach($user->contactlogs()  as $logs)

    {{ $logs->students }}

@endforeach
```

@endforeach